# PHP Spam score calculator?

Tags: php, spam

Is there software that can give an email, with full headers, a spam score? What do most people use? I've seen places like mailchimp.com show a spam calculator. What do they use to determine this score?

Answer (score 3):

On my own server, I am using [spamassassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/). It is a widely used tool *(maybe not by gmail or hotmail, but I've seen it used in several big companies and/or universities)*, which is both powerful, and works very well. The default configuration is easy to understand, and you can tune it to articulate to your precise needs, if necessary. It can also integrate other tools, if I remember correctly *(I set it up a long time ago and have not had to change anything since)*. For more information, take a look at the [spamassassinFAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/FrontPage).

SpamAssassin offers a wide variety of web user interfaces as well, which can be found on the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/WebUserInterfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Though I am not sure if Akismet can handle email, you can check it out, it recognizes patterns in the content to determine if they are spam and they also have an API.

http://akismet.com/development/api/

Comment: I'm more concerned with what the big guys use. I.e. Gmail, hotmail etc.

Comment: spamassassin is one of the industry standards